# Select min or max values within one cell (delimited string)

Tags: r, dataframe, max, min

I have a data frame where for each sample the columns can have multiple values, for example:

```
Gene       Pvalue1             Pvalue2              Pvalue3                  Beta
Ace    0.0381, ., 0.00357    0.01755, 0.001385    0.0037, NA , 0.039         -0.03,1,15
NOS          NA                  0.02              0.001, 0.00067              0.00009,25,30
```

I want to apply `min()` and `max()` for each gene's data (I have thousands of genes in total) in each column and get the smallest value for the pvalues but the largest value for columns such as the beta. So the output data would look like this:

```
Gene       Pvalue1             Pvalue2              Pvalue3                  Beta
Ace        0.00357              0.001385             0.0037                   15
NOS          NA                  0.02                0.00067                  30
```

I'm new to R and not sure if what I'm asking is possible, if there are multiple values in one cell are they viewed as strings?

Comment: Hi! It is easier if you would provide a sample that can be put into R directly.Your question "are they viewed as strings" could be easiest answered that way, but I would say they are a string indeed. Therefore I would try someting using the apply function, putting a combinations of functions in like: (for the minimum value) min(str_split()).

Comment: Hi thank you for this. I will look into the apply function and your suggested combinations of functions straight away. How can I offer a sample that goes directly into R? Apologies if this is a basic question, that sounds like it would be very useful to give.

Comment: using something like dput() will give the structure/data, the first few rows usually suffice to answer questions like this (for which you can use the head() function)

Comment: It's possible (and sometimes very useful) to have multiple numeric values in one cell `df <- data.frame(a = I(list(c(1, 2, 3))), b = 1); df[[1,1]]`; the answers thusfar assume (perhaps with justification) that this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `stringr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

getmin = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x) min(as.numeric(x),na.rm = T) ) %>%
  unlist() 

df %>%
  mutate_at(names(df)[-1],getmin)

  Gene Pvalue1  Pvalue2 Pvalue3  Beta
1  Ace 0.00357 0.001385 0.00370 -3e-02
2  NOS     Inf 0.020000 0.00067 9e-05

Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(as.numeric(x), na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

The function `getmin` extract the number with `str_extract_all`:

```
 str_extract_all(df$Pvalue2,"[0-9\\.-]+")

[[1]]
[1] "0.01755"  "0.001385"

[[2]]
[1] "0.02"
```

It has the advantage of being insensible to space or other characters, but can extract just a dot. I then loop on this list to extract in each cell the minimum, and convert the list into a vector with `unlist`. Using the `as.numeric()` function convert the possible extracted `.` to `NA`.

the code `df %>%  mutate_at(names(df)[-1],getmin)` just apply this function on all columns exept the first one

---

edit: if you want to avoid inf values, you can use this slight modified version:

```
min2 = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else min(x,na.rm = T)
getmin = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)min2(as.numeric(x)) ) %>%
  unlist() 

df %>%
    mutate_at(names(df)[-1],getmin)

  Gene Pvalue1  Pvalue2 Pvalue3  Beta
1  Ace 0.00357 0.001385 0.00370 -3e-02
2  NOS      NA 0.020000 0.00067 9e-05
```

---

data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 Gene       Pvalue1             Pvalue2              Pvalue3                  Beta
Ace    0.0381,.,0.00357    0.01755,0.001385    0.0037,NA,0.039         -0.03,1,15
                 NOS          NA                  0.02              0.001,0.00067              0.00009,25,30
                 ",header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this almost works except for some reason it values my negative numbers as positive numbers (and therefor selects the wrong min/max numbers).  This is the explanation I've understood the most so I will keep working to see if I can resolve this, thank you for your help!

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out, it seems like I need to modify ```"[0-9\\.]+"``` somehow to acconut for negative numbers, but I haven't found any similar problems. Please let me know if you know a solution to this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the negative number. You can use `[0-9\\.-]` instead, see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `regmatches` + `gregexpr` to sort out numbers, i.e.,

```
dPvalue <- t(apply(df[grep("Pvalue",names(df))], 1, function(v) {
  unlist(Map(function(x) ifelse(length(x)>0, min(as.numeric(x)),NA), regmatches(v, gregexpr("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?",v))))
}))

Beta <- apply(df[grep("Beta",names(df))], 1, function(v) {
  unlist(Map(function(x) ifelse(length(x)>0, max(as.numeric(x)),NA), regmatches(v, gregexpr("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?",v))))
})

dfout <- cbind(df["Gene"],Pvalue,Beta)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Gene Pvalue1  Pvalue2 Pvalue3 Beta
1  Ace 0.00357 0.001385 0.00370   15
2  NOS      NA 0.020000 0.00067   30
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Ace", "NOS"), class = "factor"), 
    Pvalue1 = structure(c(1L, NA), .Label = "0.0381,.,0.00357", class = "factor"), 
    Pvalue2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0.01755,0.001385", "0.02"
    ), class = "factor"), Pvalue3 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("0.001,0.00067", 
    "0.0037,NA,0.039"), class = "factor"), Beta = structure(1:2, .Label = c("-0.03,1,15", 
    "0.00009,25,30"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This also almost works, but is producing 6000+ variables, do you know why that might be? I'll keep looking into fixing this because besides that the code does run.

Comment: @DN1 If you want to keep clean in your global environment and have less variables, you can write your customized function to wrap all the things inside

Comment: Thank you I understand it better now. I have 6000+ genes and it's given me the min max of the columns that I've wanted but it tranposes the results so pvalues per gene has become a row itself. I'll look into transposing this thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using *data.table*, convert wide-to-long, split on comma, get *min* for P-values and *max* for Betas, and finally convert back to long-to-wide.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- fread("
Gene       Pvalue1             Pvalue2              Pvalue3                  Beta
Ace    0.0381,.,0.00357    0.01755,0.001385    0.0037,NA,0.039         -0.03,1,15
NOS          NA                  0.02              0.001,0.00067              0.00009,25,30
            ")

dcast(
  melt(dt1, id.vars = "Gene")[, paste0("col", 1:3) := lapply(tstrsplit(value, ","), as.numeric) 
                              ][, MinMax := ifelse(grepl("Pvalue", variable),
                                                   pmin(col1, col2, col3, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                   pmax(col1, col2, col3, na.rm = TRUE)) ],
  Gene ~ variable, value.var = "MinMax")

#    Gene Pvalue1  Pvalue2 Pvalue3 Beta
# 1:  Ace 0.00357 0.001385 0.00370   15
# 2:  NOS      NA 0.020000 0.00067   30
# Warning message:
# In lapply(tstrsplit(value, ","), as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

**Note:** same steps can be applied using `dplyr/tidyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [matrixstats](/questions/tagged/matrixstats):

```
library(data.table)
library(matrixStats)

pval_cols <- grep("Pvalue", names(DT), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)

min_fun <- function(x) {
  y <- tstrsplit(x, split = ",", fixed = TRUE)
  y <- rowMins(sapply(y, as.numeric), na.rm = TRUE)
  y <- replace(y, !is.finite(y), NA)
  return(y)
}

DT[, (pval_cols) := lapply(.SD, min_fun)
   , .SDcols = pval_cols][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DT
>    Gene Pvalue1  Pvalue2 Pvalue3          Beta
> 1:  Ace 0.00357 0.001385 0.00370    -0.03,1,15
> 2:  NOS      NA 0.020000 0.00067 0.00009,25,30
> ```

For the `Beta`-column(s) you can create a similar `max_fun`: just replace `rowMins` with `rowMaxs`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea.

```
applyFunctionToString <- function(
    string
  , sep = ","
){
    string <- gsub(" ", "", string)
    string <- unlist(strsplit(string, sep))
    string[string == "NA"] <- NA
    numbers <- as.numeric(string)
    min(numbers, na.rm = TRUE)
}

sapply(c("0.01755, 0.001385", "0.0037, NA , 0.039"), applyFunctionToString)
```

You actually want to get into string operations, convert each string into a numeric vector and then do your summary function (`min`or `max`).

The code I wrote here works in this instance, but you have to consider more factors:

- Do your strings contain other characters the need to be removed?
- What are missing values represented by?

You can also pass the function that you want to apply (`min` for example), but then you have other questions like how do you pass additional arguments to that function (using `...`) - this would be out of scope.

Hope, it still helps a little.

Comment: You should test the `str_extract` and `str_extract_all` functions from `stringr`, which allows most of what your home made function does